# How does state get encoded or encrypted in Spring OAuth2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-oauth2

**How specifically is the `state` parameter related to the `_csrf` token in Spring OAuth2?**  Is `state` an encrypted version of `_csrf` as we would expect it to be?

**Also, what specific Java syntax should be used to encode and encrypt a new `_csrf` value before encapsulating it into a new `state` parameter in Spring OAuth2?**

#### THE CONTEXT

A client app redirects the user's web browser from the client app to the authorization server's authserver/login page.  Then, in the authorization server app, a custom implementation of [`OncePerRequestFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) is used to redirect a request to `/oauth/authorize?(list of params)` into additional authentication steps, which ultimately redirect back into a new request to `/oauth/authorize?(list of params)`.   The problem is that **the `_csrf` token changes during the additional authentication steps**, and [the documentation indicates that `_csrf` is used as the `state` parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12).  This implies that **the `state` value probably needs to be updated by the authorization server to reflect the new `_csrf` value**.

#### HOW `state` IS GENERATED

The problem is that the encoded and encrypted value for `state` has already been set by the client app before the client app uses an [`OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/filter/OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java) to transfer information for the authentication server to use while authenticating the user via the authentication steps mentioned above.

Some research indicates that the `state` key is generated by the client using a [`DefaultStateKeyGenerator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/filter/state/DefaultStateKeyGenerator.java), which in turn uses a [`RandomValueStringGenrator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/common/util/RandomValueStringGenerator.java) to generate a 6 character state value.

For example, **in the original request made to `/oauth/authorize?(list of params)`, the raw `_csrf` value is encoded into `fupS1L`**, as shown in the following url:

```
/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&state=fupS1L
```

If the `_csrf` value changes to `a69fd23a-a393-4b27-a685-a323fd31db9a` during the redirect flow, the value of `fupS1L` in the state parameter will no longer be valid, and the resulting token will not be authorized to permit access to protected resources.

**What specific syntax do I use in order to convert the new `_csrf` value into an encrypted value similar to `fupS1L` that can be passed into a functional `state` parameter?**

Also, is there any relationship between the `state` variable and the `_csrf` token?  The [`RandomValueStringGenerator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/common/util/RandomValueStringGenerator.java) used by [`DefaultStateKeyGenerator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/filter/state/DefaultStateKeyGenerator.java) seems to simply create a random 6 character String.  I would like an authoritative answer by someone who has worked deeply with the code or even written it.  I am doing a deep review of the code, so a casual passer by who reads the [`RandomValueStringGenerator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/common/util/RandomValueStringGenerator.java) source code and says state is not related to the `csrf` token would not be adding any value.  The author of the API, however, would help us all out a lot by telling us how this works.

#### NOTE TO SPRING

It should not require this much digging to find documentation of such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite old since its been asked. Still sharing what I know now, as I have worked through a similar requirement to pass a deeplink in the 'state' parameter. I wanted to redirect to this deeplink when flow comes back from the auth-server after a successful oauth sign-in session.

Primarily I followed this SOF answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462787/5107365. This suggests to extend the DefaultStateKeyGenerator to use the deeplink parameter from the request to AAS to encrypt+encode to set into the 'state' parameter. And, then the custom implementation of OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.AuthenticationSuccessHandler is used to override determineTargetUrl method to decode+decrypt the state parameter when the flow comes back after successful auth. Hopefully it will help somebody who is in need of a similar requirement.